# Copying Rally workspace project from one workspace to another

Tags: rally, workspace, projects

In Rally, I want to copy some of the projects from one workspace to another newly created workspace. Has anyone tried it or has written scripts for it?

Comment: I was looking for an answer too and found this

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17795224/want-to-copy-rally-stories-from-one-project-to-another