# Want to copy Rally stories from one project to another

Tags: javascript, copy, rally

I'm trying to copy stories and tasks (and their hierarchies) from one Rally project to another.

I only need to copy from one 'template' project so I don't need to make use of the ProjectPicker widget.   Simply leveraging the existing app that copies stories and tasks is all that is need *but* it needs to be able to read from one project and write to another project (the current project you're logged into would be the easiest.)

I modified the app so that it can read from a project I'm not logged into - good.
The copy results in a copied story in the project I'm reading from - not the one I'm logged into in Rally - does anyone know how to make this happen?

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are using Story Deep Copy app.
From your question it looks like you already modified the hangman variable for a project from which you copy. Let's say the OID of that project is 22222, and the OID of the destination project where you want to copy is 33333. Both projects are in the same workspace, OID 11111.

```
var dataSource = new rally.sdk.data.RallyDataSource('11111', '22222',
                    '__PROJECT_SCOPING_UP__', '__PROJECT_SCOPING_DOWN__');
```

I added one line in `this._copyStory` :

```
foundObject.Project._ref = "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/1.29/project/33333.js";
```

Here is the entire code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html dir="ltr">
<head>
    <title>Deep Copy Story</title>
    <meta name="Name" content="App: Story Deep Copy"/>
    <meta name="Version" content="2012.01.14"/>
    <meta name="Vendor" content="Rally Software"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/apps/1.29/sdk.js?apiVersion=1.29"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    rally.StoryDeepCopy = function (rallyDataSource, config) {
            var storyBuffer = [];
            var firstStory = null;
            var finishedCallback;
            var that = this;

            function getTypeFromRef(ref) {
                if (rally.sdk.util.Ref.isRef(ref)) {
                    var list = ref.split("/");
                    list.pop();
                    return list.pop();
                }
                else {
                    throw "Function getTypeFromRef expected a Rally Reference.";
                }
            }

            //dojo.connect(obj, event, context, method, dontFix);
            this._fireEvent = function(eventName, eventArgs) {

                if (config && config.eventListeners[eventName] && dojo.isFunction(config.eventListeners[eventName])) {
                    config.eventListeners[eventName](that, eventArgs);
                }
            };

            // removes private and read only fields to keep from pushing them up.
            this.filterObject = function (object) {
                delete object.Discussion;
                delete object.Rank;
                delete object.LastUpdateDate;
                delete object.Attachments;
                delete object.AcceptedDate;
                delete object.Blocker;
                delete object.Defects;
                delete object.TaskActualTotal;
                delete object.TaskEstimateTotal;
                delete object.TaskRemainingTotal;
                delete object.TaskEstimateTotal;
                delete object.RevisionHistory;
                delete object.Subscription;
                delete object.FormattedID;
                delete object.CreationDate;
                delete object.Changesets;
                delete object.ObjectID;
                for (var j in object) {
                    if (j.substring(0, 1) == '_') {
                        delete object[j];
                    }
                }
                return object;
            };

            this._addObject = function(object, typeName, callback) {
                var item = dojo.clone(object);
                item = this.filterObject(item);
                function errorFunctionWrapper(error) {
                    if (dojo.isArray(error.Errors)) {
                        var errorMessage = error.Errors.pop();
                        if (errorMessage.indexOf("Not authorized to create:") >= 0) {
                            errorMessage = "Unable to create an object. This can happen due to a child or task being in a project you do not have write permissions to.";
                        }
                        rally.sdk.ui.AppHeader.showMessage("error", errorMessage, 10000);
                    }
                    else if(dojo.isObject(error)&&error.message){
                        rally.sdk.ui.AppHeader.showMessage("error", error.message, 10000);
                        error = [error.message];
                    }
                    if (dojo.isFunction(config.onError)) {
                        config.onError(error);
                    }
                }

                rallyDataSource.create(typeName, item, callback, errorFunctionWrapper);
            };

            this._copyAllFromBuffer = function() {
                if (storyBuffer.length > 0) {
                    var story = storyBuffer.pop();
                    that._copyStory(story.ref, story.parent, that._copyAllFromBuffer);
                }
                else {
                    if (finishedCallback) {
                        finishedCallback(firstStory);
                    }
                }
            };

            this._addStoriesToBuffer = function(storyArray, parentRef) {
                dojo.forEach(storyArray, function (story) {
                    storyBuffer.push({
                        ref: story._ref,
                        parent: parentRef
                    });
                });
            };

            this._copyStory = function(ref, parentRef, callback) {
                rallyDataSource.getRallyObject(ref, function (foundObject) {
                    var type = getTypeFromRef(ref);
                    that._fireEvent("storyPreAdd", {story:foundObject});
            console.log(foundObject.Name);
            console.log(foundObject.Project._ref);
            foundObject.Project._ref = "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/1.29/project/33333.js";
                    if (parentRef) {
                        foundObject.Parent = parentRef;
                    }
                    else {
                        foundObject.Name = "(Copy of) " + foundObject.Name;
                    }
                    that._addObject(foundObject, type, function (storyRef) {
                        if (!firstStory) {
                            firstStory = storyRef;
                        }
                        that._fireEvent("storyPostAdd", {});
                        that._addStoriesToBuffer(foundObject.Children, storyRef);
                        that._copyTasksToStory(foundObject.Tasks, storyRef, callback);
                    }, null);
                });
            };

            this._copyTasksToStory = function(tasks, storyRef, callback) {
                //Copy the array
                var localTasks = tasks.slice(0);
                if (localTasks.length > 0) {
                    var task = localTasks.pop();
                    that._copyTask(task._ref, storyRef, function () {
                        that._copyTasksToStory(localTasks, storyRef, callback);
                    });
                }
                else {
                    callback();
                }
            };

            this._copyTask = function(ref, storyRef, callback) {
                rallyDataSource.getRallyObject(ref, function (foundObject) {
                    var type = getTypeFromRef(ref);
                    foundObject.WorkProduct = storyRef;
                    that._fireEvent("taskPreAdd", {task:foundObject});
                    that._addObject(foundObject, type, function (ref, warnings) {
                        if (callback) {
                            that._fireEvent("taskPostAdd", [ref]);
                            callback();
                        }
                    }, null);
                });
            };

            this.copyStory = function (ref, callback) {
                that._copyStory(ref, undefined, that._copyAllFromBuffer);
                finishedCallback = callback;
            };
        };

    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        rally.addOnLoad(function() {
            var selectedValue = null;
            var tasksAdded = 0;
            var storiesAdded = 0;
            var searchStories;
            var goButton, chooseButton;
            var chooser;
            var waiter;
            var dataSource = new rally.sdk.data.RallyDataSource('111111', '2222222',
                    '__PROJECT_SCOPING_UP__', '__PROJECT_SCOPING_DOWN__');

            function taskPostAdd(object, args) {
                tasksAdded = tasksAdded + 1;
                displayTasksAdded(tasksAdded);
            }

            function taskPreAdd(object, args) {
                dojo.byId("currentInfo").innerHTML = "Adding Task " + args.task.FormattedID + " - " + args.task.Name;
            }

            function storyPreAdd(object, args) {
                dojo.byId("currentInfo").innerHTML = "Adding User Story " + args.story.FormattedID + " - " + args.story.Name;
            }

            function storyPostAdd(object, args) {
                storiesAdded = storiesAdded + 1;
                displayStoriesAdded(storiesAdded);
            }

            function displayStoriesAdded(count) {
                dojo.byId("storyResult").innerHTML = "Stories added: " + count;
            }

            function displayTasksAdded(count) {
                dojo.byId("taskResult").innerHTML = "Tasks added: " + tasksAdded;
            }


            function storyCopied(story) {
                dojo.byId("currentInfo").innerHTML = "Copy complete: ";
                var link = new rally.sdk.ui.basic.Link({
                    item: story,
                    text: story._refObjectName
                });

                link.display('currentInfo');
                goButton.setEnabled(true);
                chooseButton.setEnabled(true);
                if(waiter) {
                    waiter.hide();
                    waiter = null;
                }
            }

            function buttonPressed() {

                if (selectedValue) {
                    var config = {
                        eventListeners:{
                            storyPreAdd:storyPreAdd,
                            storyPostAdd:storyPostAdd ,
                            taskPreAdd:taskPreAdd,
                            taskPostAdd: taskPostAdd
                        }
                    };
                    tasksAdded = 0;
                    displayTasksAdded(tasksAdded);
                    storiesAdded = 0;
                    displayStoriesAdded(storiesAdded);
                    dojo.byId("currentInfo").innerHTML = "";
                    var copy = new rally.StoryDeepCopy(dataSource, config);
                    goButton.setEnabled(false);
                    chooseButton.setEnabled(false);
                    waiter = new rally.sdk.ui.basic.Wait({});
                    waiter.display('wait');
                    copy.copyStory(rally.sdk.util.Ref.getRelativeRef(selectedValue), storyCopied);
                }

            }

            function onChooserClose(chooser, args) {
                if (args.selectedItem) {
                    selectedValue = args.selectedItem;
                    goButton.setEnabled(true);
                    dojo.byId('storyBox').innerHTML = args.selectedItem.FormattedID + ' - ' +
                            args.selectedItem.Name;
                }
            }

            function showChooser() {
                var chooserConfig = {
                    fetch:"FormattedID,Name,Description,Project",
                    title: 'Story Chooser'
                };
                chooser = new rally.sdk.ui.Chooser(chooserConfig, dataSource);
                chooser.addEventListener('onClose', onChooserClose);
                chooser.display();
            }

            rally.addOnLoad(function () {
                goButton = new rally.sdk.ui.basic.Button({
                    text: "Copy",
                    enabled: false
                });
                goButton.addEventListener('onClick', buttonPressed);
                goButton.display('goButton');

                chooseButton = new rally.sdk.ui.basic.Button({
                    text: "Choose"
                });
                chooseButton.addEventListener('onClick', showChooser);
                chooseButton.display('chooseButton');

                showChooser();

                rally.sdk.ui.AppHeader.setHelpTopic("252");
            });
        });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
    <div style="float:left">
        <span id="chooseButton"></span>
        <span id="storyBox" style="line-height:18px;vertical-align:middle">[No story selected]</span>
        <span id="goButton"></span>
    </div>
    <div id="wait" style="float:left; height: 16px; width: 24px;"></div>
    <div style="margin-left:5px;padding-top:10px;clear:both">
        <div id="currentInfo" style="height:16px"></div>
        <div id="storyResult" style="margin-top:10px"></div>
        <div id="taskResult"></div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

EDIT: The code above was modified to use an object dropdown from which a destination project is selected. Hence there is no need to hardcode the destination project's reference.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html dir="ltr">
<head>
    <title>Deep Copy Story</title>
    <meta name="Name" content="App: Story Deep Copy"/>
    <meta name="Version" content="2012.01.14"/>
    <meta name="Vendor" content="Rally Software"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/apps/1.29/sdk.js?apiVersion=1.29"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    rally.StoryDeepCopy = function (rallyDataSource, config) {
            var storyBuffer = [];
            var firstStory = null;
            var finishedCallback;
            var that = this;

            function getTypeFromRef(ref) {
                if (rally.sdk.util.Ref.isRef(ref)) {
                    var list = ref.split("/");
                    list.pop();
                    return list.pop();
                }
                else {
                    throw "Function getTypeFromRef expected a Rally Reference.";
                }
            }

            //dojo.connect(obj, event, context, method, dontFix);
            this._fireEvent = function(eventName, eventArgs) {

                if (config && config.eventListeners[eventName] && dojo.isFunction(config.eventListeners[eventName])) {
                    config.eventListeners[eventName](that, eventArgs);
                }
            };

            // removes private and read only fields to keep from pushing them up.
            this.filterObject = function (object) {
                delete object.Discussion;
                delete object.Rank;
                delete object.LastUpdateDate;
                delete object.Attachments;
                delete object.AcceptedDate;
                delete object.Blocker;
                delete object.Defects;
                delete object.TaskActualTotal;
                delete object.TaskEstimateTotal;
                delete object.TaskRemainingTotal;
                delete object.TaskEstimateTotal;
                delete object.RevisionHistory;
                delete object.Subscription;
                delete object.FormattedID;
                delete object.CreationDate;
                delete object.Changesets;
                delete object.ObjectID;
                for (var j in object) {
                    if (j.substring(0, 1) == '_') {
                        delete object[j];
                    }
                }
                return object;
            };

            this._addObject = function(object, typeName, callback) {
                var item = dojo.clone(object);
        console.log(item);
                item = this.filterObject(item);
                function errorFunctionWrapper(error) {
                    if (dojo.isArray(error.Errors)) {
                        var errorMessage = error.Errors.pop();
                        if (errorMessage.indexOf("Not authorized to create:") >= 0) {
                            errorMessage = "Unable to create an object. This can happen due to a child or task being in a project you do not have write permissions to.";
                        }
                        rally.sdk.ui.AppHeader.showMessage("error", errorMessage, 10000);
                    }
                    else if(dojo.isObject(error)&&error.message){
                        rally.sdk.ui.AppHeader.showMessage("error", error.message, 10000);
                        error = [error.message];
                    }
                    if (dojo.isFunction(config.onError)) {
                        config.onError(error);
                    }
                }

                rallyDataSource.create(typeName, item, callback, errorFunctionWrapper);
            };

            this._copyAllFromBuffer = function() {
                if (storyBuffer.length > 0) {
                    var story = storyBuffer.pop();
                    that._copyStory(story.ref, story.parent, that._copyAllFromBuffer);
                }
                else {
                    if (finishedCallback) {
                        finishedCallback(firstStory);
                    }
                }
            };

            this._addStoriesToBuffer = function(storyArray, parentRef) {
                dojo.forEach(storyArray, function (story) {
                    storyBuffer.push({
                        ref: story._ref,
                        parent: parentRef
                    });
                });
            };

            this._copyStory = function(ref, parentRef, callback) {
                rallyDataSource.getRallyObject(ref, function (foundObject) {
                    var type = getTypeFromRef(ref);
                    that._fireEvent("storyPreAdd", {story:foundObject});
            foundObject.Project._ref = destinationProject;
                    if (parentRef) {
                        foundObject.Parent = parentRef;
                    }
                    else {
                        foundObject.Name = "(Copy of) " + foundObject.Name;
                    }
                    that._addObject(foundObject, type, function (storyRef) {
                        if (!firstStory) {
                            firstStory = storyRef;
                        }
                        that._fireEvent("storyPostAdd", {});
                        that._addStoriesToBuffer(foundObject.Children, storyRef);
                        that._copyTasksToStory(foundObject.Tasks, storyRef, callback);
                    }, null);
                });
            };

            this._copyTasksToStory = function(tasks, storyRef, callback) {
                //Copy the array
                var localTasks = tasks.slice(0);
                if (localTasks.length > 0) {
                    var task = localTasks.pop();
                    that._copyTask(task._ref, storyRef, function () {
                        that._copyTasksToStory(localTasks, storyRef, callback);
                    });
                }
                else {
                    callback();
                }
            };

            this._copyTask = function(ref, storyRef, callback) {
                rallyDataSource.getRallyObject(ref, function (foundObject) {
                    var type = getTypeFromRef(ref);
                    foundObject.WorkProduct = storyRef;
                    that._fireEvent("taskPreAdd", {task:foundObject});
                    that._addObject(foundObject, type, function (ref, warnings) {
                        if (callback) {
                            that._fireEvent("taskPostAdd", [ref]);
                            callback();
                        }
                    }, null);
                });
            };

            this.copyStory = function (ref, callback) {
                that._copyStory(ref, undefined, that._copyAllFromBuffer);
                finishedCallback = callback;
            };
        };

    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
         var destinationProject;
         function dropdownChanged(dropdown, eventArgs) {
          destinationProject = eventArgs.value
          console.log(destinationProject);
      }

        rally.addOnLoad(function() {
            var selectedValue = null;
            var tasksAdded = 0;
            var storiesAdded = 0;
            var searchStories;
            var goButton, chooseButton;
            var chooser;
            var waiter;
            var dataSource = new rally.sdk.data.RallyDataSource('1111', '2222',
                    '__PROJECT_SCOPING_UP__', '__PROJECT_SCOPING_DOWN__');

            var config = {
                type : "project",
                attribute: "Name",
                query : '(State = "Open")'
             };

          var objectDropdown = new rally.sdk.ui.ObjectDropdown(config, dataSource);
         objectDropdown.display("aDiv", dropdownChanged);

            function taskPostAdd(object, args) {
                tasksAdded = tasksAdded + 1;
                displayTasksAdded(tasksAdded);
            }

            function taskPreAdd(object, args) {
                dojo.byId("currentInfo").innerHTML = "Adding Task " + args.task.FormattedID + " - " + args.task.Name;
            }

            function storyPreAdd(object, args) {
                dojo.byId("currentInfo").innerHTML = "Adding User Story " + args.story.FormattedID + " - " + args.story.Name;
            }

            function storyPostAdd(object, args) {
                storiesAdded = storiesAdded + 1;
                displayStoriesAdded(storiesAdded);
            }

            function displayStoriesAdded(count) {
                dojo.byId("storyResult").innerHTML = "Stories added: " + count;
            }

            function displayTasksAdded(count) {
                dojo.byId("taskResult").innerHTML = "Tasks added: " + tasksAdded;
            }


            function storyCopied(story) {
                dojo.byId("currentInfo").innerHTML = "Copy complete: ";
                var link = new rally.sdk.ui.basic.Link({
                    item: story,
                    text: story._refObjectName
                });

                link.display('currentInfo');
                goButton.setEnabled(true);
                chooseButton.setEnabled(true);
                if(waiter) {
                    waiter.hide();
                    waiter = null;
                }
            }

            function buttonPressed() {

                if (selectedValue) {
                    var config = {
                        eventListeners:{
                            storyPreAdd:storyPreAdd,
                            storyPostAdd:storyPostAdd ,
                            taskPreAdd:taskPreAdd,
                            taskPostAdd: taskPostAdd
                        }
                    };
                    tasksAdded = 0;
                    displayTasksAdded(tasksAdded);
                    storiesAdded = 0;
                    displayStoriesAdded(storiesAdded);
                    dojo.byId("currentInfo").innerHTML = "";
                    var copy = new rally.StoryDeepCopy(dataSource, config);
                    goButton.setEnabled(false);
                    chooseButton.setEnabled(false);
                    waiter = new rally.sdk.ui.basic.Wait({});
                    waiter.display('wait');
                    copy.copyStory(rally.sdk.util.Ref.getRelativeRef(selectedValue), storyCopied);
                }

            }

            function onChooserClose(chooser, args) {
                if (args.selectedItem) {
                    selectedValue = args.selectedItem;
                    goButton.setEnabled(true);
                    dojo.byId('storyBox').innerHTML = args.selectedItem.FormattedID + ' - ' +
                            args.selectedItem.Name;
                }
            }

            function showChooser() {
                var chooserConfig = {
                    fetch:"FormattedID,Name,Description,Project",
                    title: 'Story Chooser'
                };
                chooser = new rally.sdk.ui.Chooser(chooserConfig, dataSource);
                chooser.addEventListener('onClose', onChooserClose);
                chooser.display();
            }

            rally.addOnLoad(function () {
                goButton = new rally.sdk.ui.basic.Button({
                    text: "Copy",
                    enabled: false
                });
                goButton.addEventListener('onClick', buttonPressed);
                goButton.display('goButton');

                chooseButton = new rally.sdk.ui.basic.Button({
                    text: "Choose"
                });
                chooseButton.addEventListener('onClick', showChooser);
                chooseButton.display('chooseButton');

                showChooser();

                rally.sdk.ui.AppHeader.setHelpTopic("252");
            });
        });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
<div id="aDiv"></div>
    <div style="float:left">
        <span id="chooseButton"></span>
        <span id="storyBox" style="line-height:18px;vertical-align:middle">[No story selected]</span>
        <span id="goButton"></span>
    </div>
    <div id="wait" style="float:left; height: 16px; width: 24px;"></div>
    <div style="margin-left:5px;padding-top:10px;clear:both">
        <div id="currentInfo" style="height:16px"></div>
        <div id="storyResult" style="margin-top:10px"></div>
        <div id="taskResult"></div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I had to add Iteration and Release to the filter function for incompatible projects, but otherwise this works great!  Thank you!